How to assign a cuda runtime function to a function pointer
Suppose I have the following code
#include <mutex>

__device__ int d_run;
__global__ void kernel()
{
    d_run = 1
}

int main()
{
    kernel<<<1, 1>>>();
    int run;
    std::once_flag flag;
    std::call_once(flag, cudaMemcpyFromSymbol, &run, "d_run", sizeof(run), 0, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
}

I got the following error message
no instance of function template "std::call_once" matches the argument list
            argument types are: (std::once_flag, <unknown-type>, int *, const char [6], unsigned long, int, cudaMemcpyKind)

It seems that the compiler cannot figure out the type of the function cudaMemcpyFromSymbol.
I know it is a made-up example. The point is that how can one save a function pointer to a cuda runtime function.

You need to specify the template type, cudaMemcpyFromSymbol<int>

Note that per documentation : "Use of a string naming a variable as the symbol parameter was deprecated in CUDA 4.1 and removed in CUDA 5.0."

@AbatorAbetor in the version I am using (from CUDA SDK 11.7) cudaMemcpyFromSymbol is not a template. Which version are you using ?

cuda has a C API and a C++ API, the later is https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/group__CUDART__HIGHLEVEL.html#group__CUDART__HIGHLEVEL_1g99db510d18d37fbb0f5c075a8caf3b5f

@AbatorAbetor I see. It seems like the OP is using the C API since they pass "d_run" as a string. Anyway I added the info for the C++ API to my answer.

passing string to the c api is also invalid according to the docs

@AbatorAbetor you are right. Rephrased accordignly.

Thanks, I just checked. It is indeed using the C++ API. It is a little confusing, since  C++ API and C API looks almost the same if one calls the runtime function directly, due to template argument deduction. The only difference is C++ API uses reference and C API uses pointer.

It seems like you use the cuda C API (since you pass "d_run" as a string, which is actually invalid - see below). In that case you can use the following workaround:
Create a trivial wrapper around the cuda runtime function, and use std::call_once with it.
The wrapper simply forwards the call to the cuda function:
#include <mutex>

__device__ int d_run;
__global__ void kernel()
{
    d_run = 1;
}

cudaError_t CUDARTAPI cudaMemcpyFromSymbol_Wrapper(void* dst, const void* symbol, size_t count, size_t offset, enum cudaMemcpyKind kind)
{
    return cudaMemcpyFromSymbol(dst, symbol, count, offset, kind);
}

int main()
{
    kernel << <1, 1 >> > ();
    int run;
    std::once_flag flag;
    std::call_once(flag, cudaMemcpyFromSymbol_Wrapper, &run, &d_run, sizeof(run), 0, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
}

Note that I passed &d_run as argument for symbol instead of a string with the symbol name, as required by the documentation.
It is mentioned there that:

Use of a string naming a variable as the symbol parameter was deprecated in CUDA 4.1 and removed in CUDA 5.0.

I.e. passing the symbol name as a string is invalid.
If you can actually use the C++ API, then as @AbatorAbetor suggested,
you simply need to specify the template type as int and pass d_run by reference:
std::call_once(flag, cudaMemcpyFromSymbol<int>, &run, d_run, sizeof(run), 0, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

